# Want to print all Keys and Values of inner dictionary at output console with nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.7

this is a code and i want to print output like
all Keys and Values of inner dictionary in output console.

```
students = {'ID 1':{'Name': 'Shaun', 'Age': 35, 'City': 'Delhi'},
            'ID 2':{'Name': 'Ritika', 'Age': 31, 'City': 'Mumbai'},
            'ID 3':{'Name': 'Smriti', 'Age': 33, 'City': 'Sydney'},
            'ID 4':{'Name': 'Jacob', 'Age': 23, 'City': 'Bangalore'}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). especially provide input, desired output and your attempt at coding a solution. do not expect people here to write code for you from scratch.

Comment: Looks like a dict, nothing else to say. What's your question? Where are your problems? What have you tried to tackle those problems? What's your desired output? What's the actual output?

Comment: Please add your expected output. I will update my answer shortly

Comment: 1)To display only keys of the inner dictionaries on the console. 2)To display only values of the inner dictionaries on the console.

Comment: want to excute this statement with nested_dict.

Comment: check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: you have to create two loops two print the values.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["ID", "Name", "Age", "City"]

for id, val in students.items():
  li = [id]
  for k,v in val.items():
    li.append(v)
  x.add_row(li)
print(x)
```

---

```
+------+--------+-----+-----------+
|  ID  |  Name  | Age |    City   |
+------+--------+-----+-----------+
| ID 1 | Shaun  |  35 |   Delhi   |
| ID 2 | Ritika |  31 |   Mumbai  |
| ID 3 | Smriti |  33 |   Sydney  |
| ID 4 | Jacob  |  23 | Bangalore |
+------+--------+-----+-----------+
```

**EDIT:**

```
for idx, (k,v) in enumerate(students.items()):
    if idx==0:
        print(v.keys())
    print(v.values())
```

---

```
dict_keys(['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
dict_values(['Shaun', 35, 'Delhi'])
dict_values(['Ritika', 31, 'Mumbai'])
dict_values(['Smriti', 33, 'Sydney'])
dict_values(['Jacob', 23, 'Bangalore'])
```

Comment: thank you for your ans but i don't want like this.

Comment: I want to print only inner keys and inner values of the Nested_dictionary. can you help me for this

Comment: 1)To display only keys of the inner dictionaries on the console.
2)To display only values of the inner dictionaries on the console.

Comment: want to dislpay this two things in output console

Comment: Thank you it's really useful for me

Comment: @DiptiThorat: If it helps, can you close the question by accepting it as an answer?